# Pandas: Drop row if it is not a date time

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains a column with dates. However, it could be possible that the datestamp is incorrect as for example in the following data with the 'blabla'.

```
import pandas as pd 
dates = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date':['2015-01-01' , '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01' , '2015-04-01', '2015-05-01' , '2015-06-01', 'blabla']})
dates
```

I would like to transform the columns with the date to datetime and drop each row when the Date column is incorrect.

```
for x in range(len(dates)):
    dates['Date'].iloc[x] = pd.to_datetime(dates['Date'].iloc[x], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

So far I can transform the column to a datetime but is there any way to drop the rows that have a incorrect datestamp? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coerce the errors and dropna i.e:

```
dates['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dates['Date'],errors='coerce')
dates.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed the _errors_ input for which I was looking for! Will accept your answer after the 10 minute rule.